# Access win32_processor propertry "Family" Dictionarie

Tags: c#

I currently work on a small project where I want to read CPU Information.
I do this by using `ManagementObjectSearcher`, `ManagementObjectCollection` and `ManagementObjects`.

```
//cpuInfo is my ManagementObjectCollection, get it from another Method

foreach (ManagementObject obj in cpuInfo)
{
try
{
     cpuFamily = obj["Family"].ToString();
     Console.WriteLine("Family: {0}", obj["Family"]);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
     cpuFamily = "Not available";
}
```

My Problem now is that cpu Family gets the Value 198.
As far as my research has gone i found out that this is the Key of a Dictionary, see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373(v=vs.85).aspx

Now my problem is, I don't know how to access this Dictionary. Haven't found any useful information so far..
Id like to access this dictionary, so no matter which Key I get, I want to get the corresponding Value.
(I thought about Hard coding the keys and Values into a Dictionary, but what if it changes over time...)

Thanks!

Another Question! What does the {0} in the Console Output means? Just found this on the net..

LINK EDITED

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Looked up the {0}, makes sense now. Thank you!

Comment: The values, like 198, 32, 33 map to Familynames like Intel Core™ i7-2760QM, Power PC Family and Power PC 601. But I dont't know how to get the Familynames with help of the keys 198,32,33, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ManagementObject "Caption" contains the Family..